# Native Ad with Appodeal

Tags: java, kotlin, admob, appodeal

I have some problem with Native Ads. I getting empy list of Native Ads. Here is code:

```
Appodeal.setAutoCacheNativeIcons(true)
    Appodeal.setAutoCacheNativeMedia(false)
    Appodeal.initialize(this, apiKey, Appodeal.NATIVE)
    Appodeal.setNativeCallbacks(object : NativeCallbacks {
        override fun onNativeLoaded() {
            Toast.makeText(this@ViewActivity, "onNativeLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun onNativeFailedToLoad() {
            Toast.makeText(this@ViewActivity, "onNativeFailedToLoad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun onNativeShown(nativeAd: NativeAd) {
            Toast.makeText(this@ViewActivity, "onNativeShown", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun onNativeClicked(nativeAd: NativeAd) {
            Toast.makeText(this@ViewActivity, "onNativeClicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    })

    val list = Appodeal.getNativeAds(5)
    nativeAd.getProviderView(this)

    Toast.makeText(this@ViewActivity, "size = "  + list.size , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

So every time I got list.size equals 0. What i did wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Disable `autocache` before initialization of `sdk` using `Appodeal.setAutoCache(Appodeal.NATIVE, false);` method.

After it, need to use cache method  `Appodeal.cache(this, Appodeal.NATIVE, 5);` after initialization of `sdk`

simple example:

```
Appodeal.setAutoCache(Appodeal.NATIVE, false);
Appodeal.initialize(this, tools.appodealApiKey, Appodeal.NATIVE)
Appodeal.cache(this, Appodeal.NATIVE, 5);
```

and move `Appodeal.getNativeAds(5);` and etc. to `onNativeLoaded()` callback.
After showing cached ads, need to use cache method again